# mysqldump does not create "CREATE/DROP" statements in SQL file

Tags: mysql

I wrote a script last year which will do a dump of the MySQL server, which is then backed up to S3 in the event of needing to recover the data in the event of data loss or when I need to work on a local copy of the site with recent data.

The problem I have is the SQL files being generated by the `mysqldump` command doesn't generate any database creation statements. So whenever I do need to use an SQL file I'm having to add them manually or add `USE db_name;` before I can import them. This is problematic with one database however, where the SQL file is well over 3GB in size.

The command I have resides in a PHP script which is then triggered via a cronjob. The command in the PHP script is:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-database --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost DB_NAME > DB_NAME.sql
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.47, yet the above command even when entered via a command line on the server doesn't include any CREATE or DROP DATABASE statements.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Why the `sql-server` tag?

Comment: Finger slipped when clicking the `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you add

`--databases yourdatabasename` to your statement that might do the trick?